# Algorithm to traverse all unblocked $1*1$ squares in a $n*m$ grid

Tags: shortest-path, square-grid

Given a $n*m$ grid, some $1*1$ squares are blocked(can't be entered) and some are unblocked(can be entered).

What is the algorithm which prints the shortest path, such that the path covers all unblocked $1*1$ squares in a $n*m $ grid ?

The starting point is given to be :$(startx,starty)$.

A $1*1$ square can be visited more than once, but all $1*1$ squares should be visited at least once and the length of path has to be minimized.

Path can end any where, when there are no more unvisited $1*1$ squares.

I have thought of dfs, but that doesn't seem to minimize the length of the path.

Comment: Related: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/68580/755.  I think the answers there imply that your problem is NP-hard (you can tell whether the corresponding graph has a Hamiltonian path by checking whether the solution to your problem avoids revisiting any square more than once; but checking for a Hamiltonian path is NP-hard).  So, there's not much hope for a polynomial-time algorithm to find the shortest such path.  However, you might be able to hope for heuristics or approximation algorithms.

Comment: @D.W.  But in my question, squares can be visited more than once

Comment: I know.  But if there's a Hamiltonian path, then the solution to your problem won't visit any square more than once; if there isn't a Hamiltonian path, the solution to your problem *will* visit some square more than once.  Consequently, if we could solve your problem, we could tell whether or not a Hamiltonian path exists (by solving your problem and then checking whether the solution visits any square more than once or not) -- which is known to be hard.

Comment: @D.W. Just for the sake of curiosity! nequit is asking for the shortest path in a specific case which is a (*planar*) rectangular grid graph. While I do not know about any specific applications of the Hamiltonian Path Problem to this case, other NP-hard problems (such as the Longest Path Problem, see "*A linear-time algorithm for the longest path problem in rectangular grid graphs*" by Keshavarz-Kohjerdi et al., Discrete Applied Mathematics, 160 (2012), pp. 210--217) are known to be solvable in polynomial time when restricted to this specific case.